# Getting the value of an .xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I am not a very experienced user yet. I am looking for a way to receive a specific value.
My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Config.xsd">
    <group name="Database">
        <setting name="server1" type="string" value="text" />
```

I try to receive the string from the value (in this case the string is called text) from the setting name "server1".

Currently I use the following code to read some xml content, which works fine for simpler use cases:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(pathtoxml);
string version = ds.Tables["Info"].Rows[0]["Version"].ToString();
versionlabel.Text = "Version:" + version;
```

It would be awesome if someone could explain me how to read it to a string.

Thank you

Edit: I doesnt display my xml content. I am working on it.

Comment: Give us an example of the xml and what you've tried already

Comment: @ziga1337 Sorry I failed posting the code. For my new approach I tested multiple solutions from Stack and MS. Sadly I simply don't manage to understand it right now.

Comment: You can use XmlDocument class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it following your `DataSet` example:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(pathtoxml);
var settings = ds.Tables["setting"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
var target = setting.FirstOrDefault(x => x["name"].ToString() == "server1");
string value = target["value"].ToString();
```

Alternatively you can use `ds.Tables["setting"].Select("name = 'server1'")` too